# Remove items from object arraylist using String array - android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have a custom ArrayList and String array. What I want is to remove a row in ArrayList which is match with the value of the String array.

My ArrayList.....

```
ArrayList<SqlFavHeaderData> hList = db.getAllHeaderDetails();
```

**SqlFavHeaderData**

```
private String mId;
private String mType;
private double mPrice;
private String mBeds;
```

String Array....

```
String[] ss = new String[i];
```

This has values that match with **mId** in the ArrayList.

What I want is to remove items from ArrayList comparing with **mId**, that matched the values in the String Array.

I tried like this.But no luck...

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        hList.remove(ss[i]); 
    }
```

Comment: You need to implement a meaningful version of `equals()` for your class if you want to use such collection methods. Beyond that: learn about java naming conventions. that hungarian notion `mSomething` is not a recommended practice in java. And use meaningful names in the first place. ss sure isn't.

Comment: try this `ArrayList<String> hList = = db.getAllHeaderDetails();
            String[] ss = new String[i];
    
            for (int i = 0; i < hList.size(); i++) {
                if (hList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(ss[i])){
                    hList.remove(ss[i]);
                }
            }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this It will remove all the items that have mID similar to your string array.

```
    for (int i=0; i< hList.size(); i++) {
        for (String mID: ss) {
            if (hList.get(i).getmId().equals(mID)) {
                hList.get(i).remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you are using java8 then you can use:

```java
      for(String mid:ss) {
            hList.removeIf(sqldata->sqldata.getmId().equals(mid));
        }
```

Comment: Use hList.get(i).getmId().equals(mID) instead of hList.get(i).getmId() == mID. == is checking reference equality. Also remove can be crash remove item with iterator.

Comment: Thankz.. There is additional *get(i)* before *remove(i)*